# Drupal 7 Rules : How to get Node Object (from Custom PHP) after a node event is triggered?

Tags: nodes, rules, actions

In Drupal 7, i am setting up a rule. That rule is applying to trigger on the `Node Save` event.

- After the `node is saved` [***Condition***] and the `rule is properly triggered`, then how can i get that saved `Node Object ($node)` from the `Execute Custom PHP Code` [***Action***]?

Because i put `var_dump($node)` (*in the Custom PHP Code Box*) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `watchdog("<pre>".print_r($node,true)."</pre>",'debug');`then see the log in admin/reports/dblog 
also you can define your own action use  `hook_rules_condition_info()`.
[This link](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token) may help.

Comment: So you mean, the output is just not visible but actually, i can directly use `$node` object from the Custom PHP (of my Rule) ?

Comment: yes,           Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: `Comments must be at least 15 characters in length` ??? @_@ what is it?

Comment: Ok @bluesky_still, i know now the output is just not visible. I CAN USE THE NODE OBJECT `$node` FROM THERE. :)